# Setting urlRoot from inside of model: backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have written the following code:

```
var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("this is parent's init function");
    },
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        id: 0
    },
    parentFetch: function() {
        this.set("urlRoot", "/cgi-bin/yoman.pl");
        console.log("debug output" + this.urlRoot + ":" + this.get("urlRoot"));

        this.fetch({
            arg: "her",
            success: function() {
                console.log("fetch success");
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("fetch error");
            }
        });
    },
    urlRoot: "/cgi-bin/hello1.pl"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("this is ready function");
    var myParent = new Parent();
    myParent.parentFetch();

});
```

Here I am trying to implement parentFetch function, in which I am setting this.urlRoot variable of the model. However, by some reason, the fetch uses old value of urlRoot, which was set at defaults.

Why does this.set("urlRoot", ...) doesn't change it's value?
Also I have printed to console the output:

```
console.log("debug output" + this.urlRoot + ":" + this.get("urlRoot"));
```

the output shows: 
debug output/cgi-bin/hello1.pl:/cgi-bin/yoman.pl

What is a problem here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set()` is used to set attributes of the model, like `name`, etc. `urlRoot` is not an attribute so `set()` can't be used to set it.

To set it, simply assign it like other object values, ie:

```
this.urlRoot = "/cgi-bin/yoman.pl";
```

instead of

```
this.set("urlRoot", "/cgi-bin/yoman.pl");
```

For reference, if you were to try `this.get('urlRoot')` or `this.attributes.urlRoot` in the model in your example you will find that they both return `"/cgi-bin/yoman.pl"` because of the `set()` call you made.